# Laravel 10 JSON column WHERE clause not filtering notifications by type - why?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

In my Laravel 10 application I'm using notifications via the database driver.
Notification data has a key `type` with a value of either `server` or `internal`, while trying to get notifications for only one type utilizing Laravels JSON Where clause like this:

```
auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('data->type', 'server');
```

I do not get any results, however using the DB query builder returns the expected data.

```
DB::table('notifications')
 ->where('notifiable_type', '=', 'App\Models\User')
 ->where('read_at','=', null)
 ->where('notifiable_id','=', auth()->user()->user_id)
 ->where('data->type', '=', 'server')
 ->get();
```

Checking the query with Laravel DebugBar shows that `json_unquote(json_extract(`data`, '$."type"')) = 'server'` is only applied using the query builder.

What could cause that behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps you want to do `auth()->user()->unreadNotifications()->where('data->type', 'server');` instead. Note the missing parentheses in your original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two things here.

Here:

```php
auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('data->type', 'server');
```

the `where` method you are calling comes from the `Collection` class.

---

Here:

```php
DB::...->where('data->type', '=', 'server')
```

the `where` method you are calling comes from the `Builder` class.

---

They are not the same. The `Builder` knows how to deal with json columns. The `Collection` doesn't have json columns. It's literally trying to find a `'data->type'` key. `->` doesn't mean anything here.

Depending on what you have `data` is casted as (object, array, other), you need to filter the data in a different way.

Try

```php
auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->filter(fn($n) => $n->data->type === 'server');
```

or

```php
auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->filter(fn($n) => $n->data['type'] === 'server');
```